# Programmatically Bookmark Link with Javascript Cross-Browser

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, bookmarks

Is there a script out there that solves this problem?  I would like to be able to say "onclick, save as bookmark".  I have searched around a bit and found [this one](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex9/addbook.htm), but it doesn't work with Safari.

Anyone have a solution for Safari?

Comment: I don't know where this urge to replicate built-in browser-functionality on site comes from; and why stop at bookmarking? While you're at it, why not add an address field, back and forward buttons,  ...

Comment: :), done most of that already.

Comment: those are some really bad practises viatropos!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm afraid that you simply can't do this in every browser. Besides, if a user want's to bookmark your page he has the tools built into  his browser ...