# Download links and bookmark in browser action with 1 click

Tags: javascript, php

How do I let users, using a one click action, 
1. download a series of links and 
2. get those links bookmarked in their browsers regardless of browser type

What will it require?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To download multiple files, you could create a hyperlink tag in javascript and fire a mouse event, simulating a click on that hyperlink.

```
var e = document.createEvent('MouseEvents'),
    a = document.createElement('a');

a.href = 'your download link';
e.initMouseEvent('click', true, false, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
a.dispatchEvent(e);
```

Do it repeatedly and you will be able to download multiple files. Please note that some browser will alert if javascript tries to download too much files at a short period of time.

---

For the bookmark thing, I don't think you can do it. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1896427/programmatically-bookmark-link-with-javascript-cross-browser).